# Differentiating automatically and manually cc-ed YouTube videos

Tags: youtube

As suggested by the title, suppose I’m given all the video links under a YouTube channel.

Is there anyway that I can tell if each video has close captions automatically generated by YouTube or manually added by users without clicking into each video link and turning on the subtitle to check its quality?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube does not support filtering an specific account's uploads to only show captioned videos.

However you can filter the search result for videos with subtitles like this.

[image: Search Filter Example]

> Search something in YouTube
>
> Click **FILTER** on the top left corner
>
> In the dropdown below, under the **FEATURES** column, there's **Subtitles/CC**. Click this.
>
> Now all results below have manually added captions.